# SSRS Authentication Issues on a fresh install

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Once again the SSRS security wall has hit me.

I did a fresh SSRS 2008R2 install.

I created a separate account (ssrs) on my box to access SSRS-related services.

Upon navigating to localhost/reportserver, I was confronted with a windows authentication popup.  I entered the ssrs username and pw and after some time was presented with the following error message:

**The permissions granted to user 'mybox\ssrs' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)**

Navigating to localhost/reports/pages/folder.aspx renders the same SQL Server Reporting Services error.

I've setup reportserver.config as follows:

```
<Authentication>
      <AuthenticationTypes>
             <RSWindowsBasic>
                   <LogonMethod>3</LogonMethod>
                   <Realm></Realm>
                   <DefaultDomain></DefaultDomain>
             </RSWindowsBasic>
      </AuthenticationTypes>
      <EnableAuthPersistence>true</EnableAuthPersistence>
</Authentication>
```

Ultimately, what I would like to do, is access the reports through my C# code, which I'm assuming I will use the authenticated user that I've setup on the box.

One [post](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Microsoft/Development/MS-SQL-Server/SQL_Server_2008/Q_26204553.html#a32899945) indicates to add the name or group to the ssrs group, which once done, doesn't work with SQLServerReportServerUser$MyBox$MSRS10_50.SQLSERVER2008R2.

Keep in mind, I am not yet able to even view any of the report services menus, as some people have had issues with.  I'm at step 1, just trying to see the services.

I've even tried logging in with my admin account on this box - no go - still a permissions issue.

Some step-by-step guidance on this would be helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several different combinations of trying, the solution has presented itself.

To recap - this is auth issue was right when trying to access localhost/reports and localhost/reportserver - couldn't even get to the Reporting Services homepage.

I had tried setting Full Control permissions for my ssrs user and Everyone on C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.SQLSERVER2008R2\Reporting Services (and all subdirectories) which did NOT work.

Ultimately, I started IE in Administrator mode (right-click on IE, select Run as Administrator), and was able to navigate to localhost/reports which goes to http://localhost/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx.

Select Folder Settings / New Role Assignment.  The New Role Assignment page will allow you to setup specific users you have setup on the box.

In my case, for now and just testing, I just have one user to access all SSRS-related items.

Incidentally, I am accessing /reports through a different browser, so the fact that I'm in IE as Admin, doesn't affect the other separate vendor instance.

Comment: Thanks, was having similar problem, I didn't get an access denied, but instead I got an almost blank page. Starting IE in Administrator let me fix the issue.